# execute a shell-script from Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pexpect

I need to call a shellscript from python.
The problem is that the shellscript will ask a couple of questions along the way until it is finished.

I can't find a way to do so using `subprocess`! (using `pexpect` seems a bit over-kill since I only need to start it and send a couple of YES to it)

**PLEASE don't suggest ways that requires modification to the shell-script!**

Comment: If its possible then you should create another shell script(2) that answers for your script(1) either using eof or read. then execute script with python subprocess.popen,

Comment: `os.system('yes | sed s/y/yes/ | ./myshell.sh')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `subprocess` library, you can tell the `Popen` class that you want to manage the standard input of the process like this:

```
import subprocess
shellscript = subprocess.Popen(["shellscript.sh"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now `shellscript.stdin` is a file-like object on which you can call `write`:

```
shellscript.stdin.write("yes\n")
shellscript.stdin.close()
returncode = shellscript.wait()   # blocks until shellscript is done
```

You can also get standard out and standard error from a process by setting `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, but you shouldn't use `PIPEs` for both standard input and standard output, because deadlock could result.  (See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html).)  If you need to pipe in and pipe out, use the `communicate` method instead of the file-like objects:

```
shellscript = subprocess.Popen(["shellscript.sh"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = shellscript.communicate("yes\n")   # blocks until shellscript is done
returncode = shellscript.returncode
```

Comment: stdout, stderr should be set in the second Popen call otherwise `.communicate()` returns `None`s (no redirection)

Comment: Ah, right--- that's what I meant, but I'll edit the answer to be more explicit.   (Or, maybe you already did?  Anyway, looks right to me now.)

Comment: also, you could `from subprocess import Popen, PIPE` to avoid `subprocess.` prefix for readability